# CSS issue with horizontal scrolling...can't find it

Tags: css

Okay, this is driving me nuts...I have this site where there is horizontal scrolling ...trying to use firebug and I can't find why it is scrolling sideways...I confirmed in both FF and IE.  Any chance I can get another set of eyes on this please and tell me what the deal is please?

[TINY URL](http://tinyurl.com/7k6a5e4)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your footer div has `width:100%` and `padding:6px;` which is forcing to have horizontal scroll.
If you remove padding then the scrolling should go away.

Comment: Oh man, totally missed that...thanks so much!!  I changed the Padding to padding-top which is where I needed it and it was all good.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `width:100%` from your footer. When it is 100%, and the side scrollbars are on, it forces it to have to scroll. The browsers usually will display it full with if not. Remember to set your `min-width:whatever` so that the footer won't become too small.

Answer (score 0):

When horizontal scrolling are showing it take width and that makes sideways scroll. reduce some width.